# Undefined Value in Array

Tags: jquery, arrays

```
class Voitures {
  code = 0;
  marque = "";
  couleur = "";
  cylindree = 0;

  constructor(code = 0, marque = "", couleur = "", cylindree = 0) {
    this.code = code;
    this.marque = marque;
    this.couleur = couleur;
    this.cylindree = cylindree;
  }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#go").click(function () {
    get(carsUrl, function (response) {
      
      let obj = JSON.parse(response);
      
      $.each(obj, function () {
          
        let voitures = new Voitures();
        voitures.code = obj["code_voiture"];
        voitures.marque = obj["marque"];
        voitures.couleur = obj["couleur"];
        voitures.cylindree = obj["cylindree"];

        
          let table = document.getElementById("table");
          
          let nouvelleRangee = table.insertRow(-1);
          let nouvelleCellule = nouvelleRangee.insertCell(0);
          let nouveauTexte = document.createTextNode(voitures.code);
          nouvelleCellule.appendChild(nouveauTexte);

          nouvelleCellule = nouvelleRangee.insertCell(1);
          nouveauTexte = document.createTextNode(voitures.marque);
          nouvelleCellule.appendChild(nouveauTexte);

          nouvelleCellule = nouvelleRangee.insertCell(2);
          nouveauTexte = document.createTextNode(voitures.couleur);
          nouvelleCellule.appendChild(nouveauTexte);

          nouvelleCellule = nouvelleRangee.insertCell(3);
          nouveauTexte = document.createTextNode(voitures.cylindree);
          nouvelleCellule.appendChild(nouveauTexte);

          nouvelleCellule = nouvelleRangee.insertCell(4);
          nouvelleCellule.insertAdjacentHTML(
            "afterbegin",
            "<input type='button' id='button_modifier' value='Modifier'>"
          );
          nouvelleCellule.insertAdjacentHTML(
            "beforeend",
            "<input type='button' id='button_supprimer' value='Supprimer'>"
          );
        });
      },
      function () {
        alert("Erreur Ajax.");
        throw new Error("Ya un problème, chef.");
      }
    );
  });
});

let carsUrl = "http://fbrc.esy.es/DWWM21050/Api/api.php/voitures/";
```

I'm trying to loop through the data (about cars, see above link) and and put each car intro a generated table. It worked for just one car, but it does not for many.

Why am I getting "undefined" and only one car?

This is a sample of the json data, which is constantly modified by a class of 12 people :

```
{
        "voitures": {
            "columns": [
                  "code_voiture",
                  "marque",
                  "couleur",
                  "cylindree"
            ],
            "records": [
               [
                    2,
                    "M2",
                    "C2",
                     112
               ],
               [
                    3,
                    "P",
                    "C",
                    110
               ],
           [...
```

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otQDO.png)

Comment: Could you provide an example of the JSON data?

Comment: @Rojo Yes : http://fbrc.esy.es/DWWM21050/Api/api.php/voitures/

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include a sample of the data. One of the keys to Stack Overflow questions is that they don't make you go to other sites just to figure out what the question is, so you know if it matches yours (if you're searching) or if you understand it well enough to answer.

Comment: Shouldn't you be iterating through `obj.voitures.records` and not just `obj`?

Comment: I'm still getting undefined tho =/

Comment: Problem resolved. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You response data structure is not matching your code parsing logic. You have to split data in columns and records. Please check below sample code.

```
let obj = JSON.parse(response);
const {columns, records}  = obj.voitures
const [code_name, marque_name, couleur_name, cylindree_name] = columns;

$.each(records, function (record) {
  const [code, marque, couleur, cylindree] = record;

  let table = document.getElementById("table");
          
  let nouvelleRangee = table.insertRow(-1);
  let nouvelleCellule = nouvelleRangee.insertCell(0);
  let nouveauTexte = document.createTextNode(code);
  nouvelleCellule.appendChild(nouveauTexte);  
})
```

You can simplify code as below:

```
fetch(carsUrl).then((response) => {
  console.log(response)
  const { columns, records } = response.voitures;
  const [code_name, marque_name, couleur_name, cylindree_name] = columns;
  let table = $("table");
  const thead = $(`<tr>
  <th>${code_name}</th>
  <th>${marque_name}</th>
  <th>${couleur_name}</th>
  <th>${cylindree_name}</th>
  </tr>`);
  table.append(thead);
  for (let record of records) {
    const [code, marque, couleur, cylindree] = record;
    const tr = $(`<tr>
    <th>${code}</th>
    <th>${marque}</th>
    <th>${couleur}</th>
    <th>${cylindree}</th>
    </tr>`);
    table.append(tr);
  }
}).catch(console.log);
```